# How to create a 4-columned, liquid footer?

Tags: css

The content of the website is two-columned with the right being fixed and the left being liquid with min and max widths. I have that down, but now I'm having problems creating a liquid, 4-columned footer to go underneath. The way that I have it makes the columns look stepped like a staircase.

I need them all to line up correctly with equal amounts of space in between as the window gets stretched. The columns themselves are also of varying widths.

EDIT

I realized a mistake I made, which caused the columns to step, so now I can move on to figuring out how to space them out evenly in the footer. This is the CSS I have:

```
#footer .col1, #footer .col2, #footer .col3, #footer .col4{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#footer .col1{
    width: 75px;
}

#footer .col2{
    width: 375px;
}

#footer .col3{
    width: 325px;
}

#footer .col4{
    width: 100px;
}
```

I used to have the widths as percentages, but it didn't evenly space them like I thought it would. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Make some simple case markup to demonstrate the problem, and this will be a much better question.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it for you:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
}

#footer .column div {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

And [in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/R4wLW/1/)

I'm using the nested `<div>` structure to show how you can achieve liquid columns with a fixed distance between.  The key when using % and fixed width dimensions is to not apply them to the same element if you want to be sure of widths.  In a live site, it would make more sense to apply the fixed horizontal margin to the nested elements rather than create a nested div structure as I have.

Your columns are most likely stepping down because they are too wide to fit together in the same horizontal line.  You'll notice in my example the width of the 4 outer div's adds up to 100%.  Anything more (say by adding margin/padding) would cause the drop you're seeing.

Comment: It's much better to add a class 'column' on each column rather than selecting all the divs. Good work setting up a demo.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried it in my code, but it's keeping the columns as equal widths. It's probably something super simple that I'm overlooking: http://jsfiddle.net/WpJBp/

Comment: @Elly I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your code.  Unfortunately using % width and fixed width as you're doing is going to create problems.  The four 25% width outer `<div>`'s will change size with the window (liquid) and so they won't always be large enough to contain your inner columns that you've used fixed widths on.  When you say "space them out evenly" do you mean: all columns same width (% or px)?  all columns different fixed widths (px) with same spacing between?  different liquid widths (%) with same spacing between?

Comment: @Pat Sorry for not clarifying earlier! What I would like to achieve is columns of different fixed widths that are always equally spaced in between as the page stretches. It is the space between that should be liquid.

Comment: @Elly Unfortunately I'm not sure this is possible.  The closest I can think of is to set a `min-width` on your `#footer` that is the sum of all 4 of your column widths + a little extra.  Then add % horizontal margins to your 4 columns...however this will be twitchy at best (i.e. can't guarantee that you won't drop your 4th column at some screen widths).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing markup I'm not sure how to fix your problem.
I would lay the page out like this:

`````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````
|body_______________   __________  |
|| left             | |   right  | |
||__________________| |__________| |
||````````````````````````````````||
|| footer                         ||
|| |``````||``````||``````||``````|| 
|| | .col ||.col  || .col || .col ||
````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````

with the css:

```
#footer { width:100%; clear:both; }

#footer .col {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Only thing to add is that he wanted the footer columns of varying width - `width: auto;` and the spacing the same, `margin: 0, 2.5%`.  Otherwise, yeah, I'd approach it the same way.